# How to add one more CAGradientLayer to UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit, cagradientlayer

I have a PopupView with a scrollable label (like Marquee type). Its scrolled inside a `labelView`, which is just a `UIView`.

I decided to add an effect of transparent gradient to the left and right sides of `labelView` using the following code:

```
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0, 0.2, 1]
    
    gradientLayer.frame = labelView.bounds
    labelView.layer.mask = gradientLayer
```

But the effect is visible only on the left side of the `labelView`. Right side is unchanged:

[image]

How can I apply the same gradient to the `labelView` right side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your start/end points and your color locations

In a linear Gradient locations are relative points where [colors] are presented.

```
  0 0.2   0.8 1
  |--|-----|--|
```

so from 0 to 0.2 (20% of total length) we will have a gradient of clear to white, then from 0.2 (20%) to 0.8 (80%) a gradient from white to white (solid white) and from 0.8 (80%) to 1 (100%) a gradient from white to clear color.

From apple https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cagradientlayer/1462410-locations

> Discussion
> The gradient stops are specified as values between 0 and 1. The values must be monotonically increasing. If nil, the stops are spread uniformly across the range. Defaults to nil.

When rendered, the colors are mapped to the output color space before being interpolated.

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)
gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor]
gradientLayer.locations = [0, 0.2, 0.8, 1]

gradientLayer.frame = labelView.bounds
labelView.layer.mask = gradientLayer
```

**After Updated answer**

[image]

Comment: Hi Reinier! Thank you for the reply! I did try your solution and receive a desired effect, but it's too big from both sides of UIView: https://share.cleanshot.com/oo6y2Z How can I make it smaller like in my initial post? If I increase x number then right side became "ungradient" again, if smaller - right side became invisible...

Comment: @artexhibit I had updated my answer ;). Changing the positions to `[0, 0.2, 0.8, 1]` and adding a new `UIColor.white` in colors array should be enough. enjoy

Comment: Oh, I got the idea. Thank you very much! Solved!

Comment: @artexhibit I added additional info of how Gradiend.locations works

Comment: Reinier, thank you! Now the gradient work became completely clear for me.